# Código não é executado em linha de comando

Tags: php

Eu tenho um arquivo `teste.php` com o seguinte código.

```
 <?
 echo "teste";
 ?>
```

Quando executo no terminal o comando `php -f teste.php` recebo como output o meu código:

```
 <?
 echo "teste";
 ?>
```

ao invés de:

```
teste
```

O que está acontecendo?

Comment: Tente abrir as tags normais <?php ?>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O problema está na sua abertura de tags `<?`

Para utilizá-las é preciso habilitar na configuração do `php.ini` a opção `short_tags_open` para `on`. Mais informações sobre [essa configuração aqui](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag).

Por outro lado, é **altamente desaconselhável** o uso de `short_tags_open` pois elas podem conflitar com o cabeçalho de arquivos `XML` (`<?xml version="1.0"?>`).

Tanto que essa configuração poderá ser [removida na versão futura no PHP](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/remove_alternative_php_tags), como é o caso das tags estilo ASP `<% %>` (configuração [`asp_tags`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/ini.core.php#ini.asp-tags))

**Resumindo**

Utilize `<?php` em todos seus scripts.

É mais seguro pois ira funcionar em qualquer servidor PHP, não será removido no futuro e você não terá dores de cabeça ao trabalhar com XML.